# web3 python exactInputSingle keeps failling

Tags: uniswap, web3.py, ethereum-classic

I Am trying to make a swap on uniswap using its routerV3's exactInputSingle function like this:

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
from web3.gas_strategies.time_based import fast_gas_price_strategy #♦, medium_gas_price_strategy, slow_gas_price_strategy
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware
import json
from time import time

w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(rpc))

w3.eth.set_gas_price_strategy(fast_gas_price_strategy)
w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)

router_address = '0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564'
router_abi = json.loads(...)
erc20_abi = json.loads(...)

wallet_address = 'XXX'
private_key = 'XXX'

router_contract = w3.eth.contract(address=universal_router_address, abi=router_abi)

weth_address = w3.to_checksum_address('0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2')
usdc_address = w3.to_checksum_address('0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7')

weth_contract = w3.eth.contract(address=weth_address, abi=erc20_abi)
usdc_contract = w3.eth.contract(address=usdc_address, abi=erc20_abi)

print(weth_contract.functions.balanceOf(wallet_address).call() / 10**18) # 0.2392

amountIn = int(0.004*10**18)

ExactInputSingleParams = (
    weth_address,
    usdc_address,
    10000,
    wallet_address,
    int(time())+10*60
    amountIn,
    1,
    0
)

func = router_contract.functions.exactInputSingle(ExactInputSingleParams)

params = {
    "from": wallet_address,
    "value": amountIn,
    'gasPrice': w3.eth.gas_price,
    'gas': 53000,
    "nonce": w3.eth.get_transaction_count(wallet_address),
    'chainId': w3.eth.chain_id,
}

txn = func.build_transaction(params)
signed_tx = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(txn, private_key)

txn_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
```

But that transaction keeps failling. Any idea why?